# NSPopUpButtonCell Subclass Animates Closed With Standard Appearance

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, nspopupbuttoncell

I've created an NSPopUpButtonCell subclass to customize its appearance.

When one of the menu items is selected from the popup it animates the selection with the standard popup appearance on OS X 10.10.

I'd like it to animate with my custom appearance.

**Customized PopUp**

[image: Customized PopUp]

**Animating Selection**

[image: Animating Selection]

**My Implementation**

```
- (void)drawBezelWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] saveGraphicsState];

    NSBezierPath *rectanglePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame xRadius:5.0 yRadius:5.0];
    [[NSColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:1.0] setFill];
    [rectanglePath fill];

    float width = frame.size.width;
    float height = frame.size.height;

    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];

    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(width - 5, height/2 - 2)];
    [path lineToPoint:CGPointMake(width - 10, height/2 - 7)];
    [path lineToPoint:CGPointMake(width - 15, height/2 - 2)];


    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(width - 5, height/2 + 2)];
    [path lineToPoint:CGPointMake(width - 10, height/2 + 7)];
    [path lineToPoint:CGPointMake(width - 15, height/2 + 2)];

    [path setLineWidth:2.0];

    [[NSColor darkGrayColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn off bordered property on Interface Builder.

If bordered is actualy off, you have to switch it on and next off.

Better way is use 
- (void)drawBorderAndBackgroundWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView